# How do I get the key from Map in a List and do a get rest request in Java

Tags: java, rest

I want to do a get request and want to get all the jobs who have the "teacher" in it. In this case the map value 2 and 3.

How do I get there if I execute the code below then I only get the value from the Map 2. The best way is over a List? But how do I do it?

I have this method.

```
@GET
@Path("jobs")
public Job getJobsId(@QueryParam("id") int id, @QueryParam("description") String description) {

    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println("I DID IT");
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            return berufe.get(entry.getKey());
        }

    }
    return berufe.get(id);
}
```

and this Map:

```
jobs.put(1, new jobs(1, 1337, "student"));
jobs.put(2, new jobs(2, 420, "teacher"));
jobs.put(3, new jobs(3, 69, "schoolteacher"));
```

**---------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------**

If I do this:

```
@GET
@Path("jobs")
public Collection<Job> getJobsId(@QueryParam("id") int id, @QueryParam("description") String description) {

    final Set<Beruf> result = new HashSet<>();

    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase()) == true) {

            result.add(jobs.get(entry.getKey()));
        } else {
          return jobs.values();
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

I get with a discription all Map values back and without I get an Error.

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getJobsId()` returns on the first item it finds (inside the `if` statement), that's why you only get one result.

The usual pattern to collect a number of results would be to instantiate a suitable `Collection` before the `for` loop, and add each item that is found to this collection. Then, after the `for` loop, return the collection. I don't understand your code completely, but it would be something similar to the below (I'm sure it won't work if you just copy-paste, so read and understand what is going on ;-) ):

```java
Set<Beruf> result = new HashSet<>();
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase())) {
    result.add(berufe.get(entry.getKey()));
  }
}
return result;
```

Since Java 8, it has been much more concise (readable) to use the `Streams` interface and call `.filter` (and maybe `.map`) on it, then `.collect` the stream to a suitable collection and return that. Something similar to:

```java
return jobs.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(entry -> (entry.getValue().getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase())))
  .map(entry -> berufe.get(entry.getKey()))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Okay but how do I do this (with code example)? If I want to add it then it is null...

Comment: @Phil updated with some code.

Comment: Ty. Works well for my code :).

Comment: How do I can change the Code that with this method I get all jobs if I don't use any QueryParam and if I use one like teacher that it only shows me the teachers?

Comment: You expand the expression in your `if` statement (or `.filter`) so that the expression evaluates to `true` when no query params are set. Simple.

Comment: @frlT updated my question maybe you can help me

Comment: Hi @Phil, the concept you are asking about now is different from what your original question was about. But it seems to me that you have not yet grasped the working of `return` statements despite the previous answer, nor understand `if` statements. These are **basic** concepts that are normally taught at the very start of a course/book (irrespective of language), and with which one could be expected to be familiar with by the time one works on web services. Unfortunately I'll have to refrain from wasting further time on this thread; I suggest you revisit your training/reference material.

Answer (score 0):

A function can return only one element. If there more than one hit, you have to return an object that can take on multiple elements. As you already mentioned a list, as an representant of a collection, can do this job. For your use case is a map a better option:

```
@GET
@Path("jobs")
 public Job getJobsId(@QueryParam("id") int id, @QueryParam("description") String description)
 {
    //Declare an object that can take on multiple elements
    var Map<Job> jobList = new HashMap<>();
    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet())
    {
        if (entry.getValue().getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(description.toLowerCase()))
        {
                System.out.println("I DID IT");
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                jobList.put(entry.getKey(), job.get(entry.getKey()));
        }
    
    }
    return jobList.get(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do is design the API correctly, for example:

```
@GET
@Path("jobs")
public List<Integer> searchJobsIdByDescription(@QueryParam("description") String description) {
    ...
}
```

Important: you must give a suitable name to the method (f.e: `searchJobsIdByDescription`), your method should only do one thing, so you declare only the parameters needed to do that thing (f.e: `(@QueryParam("description") String description)`) and return the expected type (`List<Integer>`).

Pay attention to the annotation `@Path("jobs")`, you have to avoid matching the previous ones

Next, you should carefully read @frIV's answer